# Domain Access separate home page per domain does not work

Tags: 7, domain-access

I have 3 domains set up on my dev machine.
1)drupalx
2)drupaly
3)localhost

Hello, I am using:

Domain Access 7.x-3.11 (with at domain configuration and domain setting enabled)
Internationalization 7.x-1.10.

I JUST enabled domain configuration/domain settings modules to try and get a separate home page per domain. Before I was using domain access without these 2 helper modules.

I am attempting to set my home page per domain.  There appear to be 3 ways to do this and none of them are working correctly.

Option 1) setting the values in /config/system/site-information

With this approach and Domain Access there is a domain access section at the bottom of the site-information page. You are supposed to set the home page and then choose which domain it is for and then save. In this domain access section it is supposed to show all the domains you have created, but mine says "localhost" for all of them.  Looking at domain access options for my content types (related side topic) shows that now the options for the other domains are missing there as well. It ONLY says "localhost".  It used to say localhost, drupalx, drupaly, but as I saved the front page for each of those domains the save process changed the machine name for drupalx and drupaly to "localhost" I am able to go back to each domain individually and change back it's machine name (but weird that it changes that).
After saving I get a message 
"The configuration options have been saved for localhost. These settings will be inherited unless overridden per domain." Meaning it is saving that front page for every domain available (checking confirms this)
[image]

Option 2) First setting section in "admin/structure/domain/view/2/config"
Here you can set a separate home page per domain but when you go to the home page of those domains there is no front page defined (it just doesn't work).
[image]

Option 3) Second settings section in "admin/structure/domain/view/1/variables"
Here you just set the front page per domain.  Anytime I put any value in here after the page saves and reloads that value is gone, re-replaced by "node".  This does not work either.
[image]

I only enabled domain configuration and domain setting modules to try and get some extra configuration options to set my front pages per domain.  Didn't get me anywhere.
I of course tried to set the home page before enabling domain configuration and domain setting modules, and that didn't get me anywhere either.

Anyone have any front page advice for any of these front page configuration settings I tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using panels, you can create one homepage, but with separate variants for each domain. We use this approach for ~12 sites running on one drupal instance.

Comment: This is not solution for asked question - why is it accepted? I'm facing the same problem, but I'm not using panels...

Answer (score 0):

I am using the technique you labeled "option 2" above; it works fine.  I put "node/835" in for the site frontpage for one domain, and that node is in fact shown as the front page for that domain.

One striking thing that I notice in your screenshots above is that your URLs read `http://localhost/projects`.  Domain access is designed to use the domain name from the http headers to select which subsite to use.  You should add entries to your etc/hosts file for dev.subsite1.domain.com, dev.subsite2.domain.com, and so on, all pointing to localhost (127.0.0.1).  You'll also need to set up a virtual host configuration file for each of your subsites.  In the "aliases" tab for subsite1.domain.com, add an entry for "dev.subsite1.domain.com", and so on for each of your subsites.

If you do all of this, and if you have also added the requisite `include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/domain/settings.inc';` to the end of your settings.php file, then your domain access settings such as the front page configuration should work just fine.

Comment: Hello, thanks for writing. localhost was added to the "host" file, along with the other domains (with virtual host configuration set up). I ended up going the panels way because in order to do option 1 or option 2 you to have domain configuration/domain settings installed and Since I am using domain access with domain variables it is not recommended (by Domain Access) to use those 2 modules with the domain variables module.